# How to access MySQL running on an EC2 instance from Lambda?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda

Is it possible to use Lambda(triggered by AWS IoT) to read/write to a MySQL server running on an EC2 instance? If so how would you do that? All info I see on internet seems to relate specifically to Amazon RDS rather than EC2 instances.

Thanks, Marcus

Comment: You would access it exactly same as RDS, by connecting to it using mysql client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect the Lambda to the subnet where the MySQL server is running. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html.

Once that is done, you can connect to it using the server's private IP, as you normally would any MySQL server.